# Настройки пользователя

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу программу, в которой есть настройки
При каждом запуске программы настройки становятся дефолтными
Думал, сделать файл .txt, в который будут записываться параметры и считывать с него. Но уже этот вариант мне не очень нравится
Какие варианты можно еще использовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А почему никто до сих пор не предложил [`Settings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Это стандартный. рекомендованный Microsoft путь. За вас сделано версионирование и миграция, чтение-запись типизированных данных, разделение настроек на настройки приложения и специфические настройки пользователя. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Answer (score 1):

1. DB. (SQLite)
2. XML.
3. BinaryStream (хотя не желательно)
4. [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Под Windows можно создать под программу раздел в реестре HKCU\Software\You\Your software\ и в нем хранить настройки для пользователя. По идее, реестр на то и нужен, причем ветка пользователя создавалась специально под настройки ОС и ПО для конкретного пользователя.

Под Линукс вариант хранить в ~.software-rc вроде как стандартный (но давно это было).