# Насколько верно будет хранить одну переменную в базе данных

Tags: c#, asp.net, архитектура

Есть задача хранить timestamp где то вне приложения, переменная будет иногда изменяться. Где лучше это делать? Создать отдельную таблицу в базе данных и хранить там одну переменную или есть другие способы? Приложение на ASP NET 5

Переменная нужна для сверки с таблицей Excel. Подробнее:
Есть эксель файл, он изменяется пользователями, там есть колонка timestamp, которая обновляется если в строке что то изменилось.

Задача переменной timestamp хранить последнюю временную метку которая была уже обработана.

**Как все происходит?**

Сервис берет timestamp, свреяет его с данными из колонки в экселе, если там будут метки большие чем timestamp  то эти данные изменялись и надо их взять. После мы присваиваем переменной timestamp самую позднюю временную метку из тех строк что мы обработали.

Comment: Вы бы рассказали, что это за таймштамп, для чего эта переменная, как часто будет меняться, почему нужна персистентность. Пока вопрос настолько расплывчатый, что советы будут универсально-бесполезными.

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим оратором: изложите требования к сохраняемому значению.

Comment: Я бы хранил эту дату в CustomDocumentProperties самого Excel-файла.

Comment: @Akina но у меня не всегда есть возможность писать в файл, так как он может быть открыт пользователем, а читать я могу всегда. И если сделать как вы сказали, возникает ситуация что данные обновились, мы все что надо взяли, теперь надо поправить  timestamp но увы файл открыт пользователем и наш timestamp завис в воздухе и если сервис вдруг упадет, данные нового timestamp  не сохранятся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, использовать базу данных нужно тогда, когда у вас появляются [ACID-требования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID): атомарность, согласованность, изоляция и отказоустойчивость.

В вашей ситуации таких требований не видно, поэтому я бы просто положил данные в `Settings` ([[1]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446103/10105), [[2]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet)). Вы получаете бесплатно хранение и типизацию данных. (А так, можно хранить хоть в текстовом файле.)

---

Если user-level settings недоступны из-под ASP.NET, <s>судя по всему, рекомендованный Microsoft путь — помещать данные в [Application State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx)</s> вам нужно хранить данные в файле в App Data.

Доступ к каталогу App Data [можно получить так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1268738/276994):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/имя файла.dat");
```

или

```
string appDataDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
string path = Path.Combine(appDataDir, "имя файла.dat");
```

Comment: Понял спасибо, в моем случае это видимо будет Web.config так как проект на ASP NET и файла  .settings  в разделе Properties у меня нет

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov у вас asp.net и вам это решение не подойдет совсем никак - т.к. вы просто не сможете сохранить в settings измененное значение - у вас все настройки из settings будут с scope=application и readonly-доступом

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @VladD ApplicationState - это просто статическая переменная, которая умирает при перезагрузке приложения (т.е. минут через 20 неактивности)

Comment: @PashaPash: И правда, уже прочитал в документации. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В случае ASP.NET у вас не так много вариантов:

- Хранить данные где-то в папке App_Data (в текстовом файле, например). Нормальный вариант в случае, если приложение хостится у вас на сервере, полностью под вашим контролем, и база данных у вас в приложении больше ни для чего не используется.
- Хранить данные в базе данных (SQL Server/MongoDB/Redis с persistence). Предпочтительный вариант, если база данных у вас уже есть.

Хранить состояние в базе данных - это абсолютно нормально, именно для этого они и придуманы. Нет никаких ограничений "в базе должны храниться только данные с ACID-требованиями" - храните где угодно и что угодно (только большие файлы не складывайте прямо в базу :)

Comment: На мой вкус, заводить базу данных для хранения одной переменной — дикий overkill. Это для меня выглядит как для сложения чисел использовать WebBrowser + скрипт на js.

Comment: @VladD ну а куда вы еще предлагаете в ASP.NET данные складывать? Там из доступного на запись - одна папка App_Data, и то это ненадежный вариант в случае нормальных хостингов (т.к. приложение может быть одно, а физических серверов под ним - два и больше).

Comment: @VladD это плата за масшабируемость и возможность сделать 99.99% аптайм. из реальных альтернатив - только другие внешние хранилища, вроде nosql баз - mongodb, redis с persistence. Или что-то специфическое для хостинга - azure tables, например. :(

Comment: Эээ, ну если `App_Data` — ненадёжное место, то и база данных, выходит, тоже ненадёжное место?

Comment: @VladD App_Data  - это папка на диске. она ненадежна в том смысле, что если приложение запущено на нескольких физических серверах - то на каждом своя папка и свое значение переменной :) Ну или например хостер может взять и переселить приложение на другой сервер. Плюс многие системы деплоя любят разворачивать каждую версию приложения в новой папке, с чистой App_data. Т.е. App_data - это надежный вариант в случае, если над окружением есть полный контроль (т.е. когда это действительно одна папка на одном диске), но ненадежный в случае какого-нибудь Azure Cloud Services или модных контейнеров.

Comment: @VladD, есть ведь всякие Nosql базы, позволяющие хранить параметр или коллекцию параметров просто по ключу, например. Как раз то что надо, думаю

Comment: @PashaPash: Эээ, стойте, у нас уже появляются типичные для базы данных требования :) Если у нас вдруг вместо одной переменной стало «распределённая по хостам переменная», то у нас сразу начинаются CAP-проблемы.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Не, всё ещё не убеждён, что нужно поднимать (любую) базу данных для хранения 4 байт.

Comment: @VladD к сожалению, не могу стоять, это не от меня зависит. У топикастера asp.net со всеми вытекающими - одновременными запросами (даже на одном хосте с одним пользователем в системе), readonly окружением и прочим - т.е. даже с App_Data он, теоретически, может получить проблемы при двух одновременных запросах на обработку.

Comment: @VladD вы просто думаете о базе данных как о чем-то тяжелом и требующем "подъема". на практике в asp.net core поднять mongodb/redis/что угодно - это 5 строк в конфиге compose или kubernetes + подключение nuget пакета. Там работы сравнимо с записью в app_data, если не меньше :)

Comment: @VladD, да и база у автора уже есть, вроде. А то что она берет на себя всю работу по обеспечению одновременного доступа - дает ей преимущество

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, поскольку я более-менее представляю себе, что у базы данных _внутри_ (я как-то писал движок), о да, это _очень_ тяжёлая штука. То есть может быть это легко отконфигурировать, но с моей точки зрения это всё ещё выглядит как поднимать авиацию для разгона голубей.

Comment: @VladD предложите альтернативу, все веб разработчики будут вам благодарны. я боюсь подумать, какие ассоциации у вас вызовут современные способы деплоя вроде kubernetes.

Comment: @PashaPash: ну, я в веб-разработке суммарно 0 ч. 00 мин., а вы уже спрашиваете у мня совета, как сделать всё хорошо. Текущее состояние с базой-данных-для-одной-переменной вызывает у меня такое же примерно недоумение, как ситуация с веб-фронтэндом у автора [вот этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/341692/).

Comment: @VladD автор той статьи почему-то считает, что веб-программирование - это только View из MVC. Это примерно как удивляться "что там в WPF такого интересного, это же просто кнопочки на форме, сиди и код в onclick вписывай, винформ же хватало". На самом деле в веб на скрипте пишут presentation logic, а не кнопочки рисуют.

Comment: @PashaPash: Да, у него там есть различие между webapp, наподобие gmail, и более-менее статическим контентом, наподобие википедии.

Comment: @VladD По поводу оверхеда на базу - это нормально. Пока java/.net думали об оверхеде, появился nodejs и за счет простоты (и адского оверхеда) отъел рынок. А сейчас asp.net core пытается откусить от этого рынка кусок. Я с нодой на вы, написал на ней только вебморду к аквариуму. Там 6 кнопок в интерфейсе + вебсокеты для обновления их состояния. Строк 80 кода. И 29 мегабайт подключенных модулей (js файлов, а не dll). И все это работает быстро. На raspberry pi. Современная разработка, чтоб ее

Comment: @PashaPash: Ага, ну если каждую проблему пробивать миллионнократным расходом ресурсов, а не вдумчивым и экономным планированием, то, понятно, скоро появится многохостовая нода, и средний веб-сервер будет занимать дюжину мощных хостов. А если с async/await, то и полсотни. Ура, профессия программиста никогда не потеряет актуальность! (Впрочем, мы, кажется, в оффтопике, нас нужно в чат по C#.)